# Stable Planar Graphs Under Hooke's Law

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

Given a planar graph, i. e. a graph $G=(V,E)$ with a map $p\colon V\to\mathbf{R}^2$ (could also be $\mathbf{R}^n$), we can imagine the edges being springs following Hooke's law.  I write $\text{len}_p(e)$ for the length of $e:=\{v,v'\}$ under $p$, i. e. $\|p(v')-p(v)\|$.  So for another planar map $p'\colon V\to\mathbf{R}^2$ we can compute the force on some vertex $v\in V$ as $$\sum_{v'\in V\colon (e:=\{v,v'\})\in E}(\text{len}_{p'}(e)-\text{len}_p(e))(p'(v')-p'(v))/\text{len}_{p'}(e)$$ (if I'm not mistaken).  I did some simulations and realized that (obviously) for some planar graphs $(G,p)$, there are alternative planar maps $p'$ which are not congruent to $p'$ but still stable, i. e. all forces sum up to $0$.  (Some of them are trivial in the sense that all springs retain their rest length, but there are non-trivial ones as well.)  I was just curious if this has been studied in graph theory, or alternatively the question, given $k$ points in $\mathbf{R}^2$, what is the least amount of springs needed to turn the configuration into a stable graph as defined above?

Comment: Could you give an example of an *unstable* graph? Assuming no crossings, *every* system like this should settle into a zero-force equilibrium. Even assuming the vertices are immovable, every edge generates two equal opposing forces by N3L. So: (1) Are the vertices fixed in $\mathbb{R}^n$? (2) Are you trying to get zero net force on *each* vertex? (3) Do all the springs have the same spring constant? (If all of the above, the answer is likely "nope, you can't do that.")

Comment: Ah, maybe stable was not the best word, like I described, stable I mean there is only one configuration (up to conngruence).  For example, when you have a line graph, you can have different angles between line segments, so multiple, non-congruent variations which all have the same edge length and hence zero net force.  Non-trivial example, but with crossings, would be the graph with $6$ vertices and edges between all but opposite vertices with a map forming a regular hexagon, you can take every other vertex and map them onto their opposite vertex, this is a also a net zero configuration.

Comment: OK, I'm still not quite understanding your description. What do you mean by "only one configuration up to congruence"? More specifically I'm trying to figure out what you mean by "configuration." Is, for instance, $C_6$ a stable graph? Or $K_6$?

It *seems* like the idea is that you take a set of connections into real space with the map $p$, where are the edges have specific lengths, but their springs are at rest ($F = k \Delta x = 0$). Then you move the vertices to the map $p'$ and see what the net forces are based on the new lengths of the edges.

Comment: With configuration I mean map.  Sorry, I'm not really using the planar graph property, I should have named it differently, I just mean graphs whose vertices have coordinates.  Somebody else added the tag planar-graph to my question, I hope that's not confusing.  I'm not sure if $C_6$ is stable, but the way you described it is what I meant.  The triangle is stable for example.

Comment: Where you say "where are the edges have specific lengths, but their springs are at rest", this is not a "but", the specific lengths are exactly the rest lengths of the springs, so they are trivially at rest.

Comment: To give a more intuitive idea, I did a simulation where I randomized the coordinates of all vertices and then let the springs do they work, in some cases, the original graph will always reassemble itself from those random positions, e.g. a triangle.  I also did a hexagon with an extra vertex at the center, edges from the center to all the the other vertices plus between opposite vertices (so 9 edges).  This one also seemed stable, but that's only anecdotical data.

Comment: OK, I think I see. We stretch or compress the springs by moving the vertices (or attachment points) of the springs from $p$ to $p'$. Then we want to know, will the graph return to its original configuration or not in order to come back to equilibrium?

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea!

Comment: From a physics-teacher standpoint, I think the answer is always going to be "yes."